# Implement External API into Wordpress

Tags: api, wordpress-version

I am trying to implement parts of an external api found here (http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/) into my wordpress theme.

However I have no idea to get the data from X to Y.

I have tried using this code

```
$uri = 'http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/leagueTable';
$reqPrefs['http']['method'] = 'GET';
$stream_context = stream_context_create($reqPrefs);
$response = file_get_contents($uri, false, $stream_context);
$fixtures = json_decode($response);

echo stripslashes($fixtures);
```

to no avail as it displays the data as unformated api data with links everywhere....

Comment: Try a print recursive print_r($fixtures); echo is for strings, not arrays.

Answer (score 1):

First, I highly recommend you get to know your data model before doing anything.  For this purpose I recommend dumping the raw JSON into a linter or formatter (e.g. [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)) to see what you're dealing with.

That said, what Brian suggests is appropriate -- you should take a look at the object you produced from `json_decode` by passing it through `print_r`.  Without knowing exactly what you're up to, it's tough to make any specific recommendations, but since most of the data appears to be embedded within the `standing` property, I'll give you a contrived example of how you could work through those, rendering a `<ul>...</ul>` for each standing and an accompanying league caption title:

```
<h1><?php echo esc_html($fixtures->leagueCaption); ?></h1>
<?php
foreach($fixtures->standing as $standing) {
    ?>
<ul>
    <li><strong>Position:</strong> <?php echo $standing->position; ?></li>
    <li><strong>Team:</strong> <?php echo $standing->position; ?></li>
    <li><strong>Games Played:</strong> <?php echo $standing->playedGames; ?></li>
    <li><strong>Points:</strong> <?php echo $standing->points; ?></li>
    <li><strong>Goals:</strong> <?php echo $standing->goals; ?></li>
    <li><strong>Goals (Against):</strong> <?php echo $standing->goalsAgainst; ?></li>
    <li><strong>Goals (Difference):</strong> <?php echo $standing->goalsDifference; ?></li>
</ul>
    <?php
}
?>
```